# Selector not working when targeting div up one level

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm embedding a `HubSpot` form on a page. On this form, I'm trying to achieve functionality where, on `focus`, the label moves up. Something like this:

```css
form {
  display: inline-block;
}
.field {
  padding-top: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
label {
  order: -1;
  padding-left: 5px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  transform: translateY(20px);
  pointer-events: none;
}
input:focus + label {
  transform: translateY(-2px);
}
```

```html
<form class="form">
  <div class="field">
    <input type="text">
    <label>Name</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

However, `HubSpot` form markup is uneditable and all over the place, so I'm trying to target a `label` that is outside of the `container` of the `input`. See below for demo:

```css
.hs-form-field {
  position: relative;
}
.hs-form-field input, .hs-form-field textarea, .hs-form-field select {
  outline: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 50%;
}
.hs-form-field > label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(15px, -50%);
}
.hs-form-field input:focus {
  color: red;
}
.hs-form-field input:focus + ~ .hs-form-field > label {
  transform: translate(10px, -30px);
}
```

```html
<div class="hs-form-field">
  
  <label>
    <span>First name</span>
  </label>
  
  <div class="input">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  
</div>
```

As you can see, on `focus`, I'm trying to target the above selector, but upon inspect, nothing shows, so something isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:focus-within` might be what you're looking for. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/focus-within/

```
.hs-form-field:focus-within label {
  transform: translate(10px, -50px);
}
```

```css
.hs-form-field {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}
.hs-form-field input, .hs-form-field textarea, .hs-form-field select {
  outline: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 50%;
}
.hs-form-field > label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(15px, -50%);
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.hs-form-field input:focus {
  color: red;
}
.hs-form-field:focus-within label {
  transform: translate(10px, -50px);
}
.hs-form-field input:focus + ~ .hs-form-field > label {
  transform: translate(10px, -30px);
}
```

```html
<div class="hs-form-field">
  
  <label>
    <span>First name</span>
  </label>
  
  <div class="input">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can control `lable` by placeholder attribute.

```css
.floating-form {
  width:320px;
  margin-top:2rem;
}

/****  floating-Lable style start ****/
.floating-label { 
  position:relative; 
  margin-bottom:20px; 
}
.floating-input  {
  font-size:14px;
  padding:4px 4px;
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:30px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border:none;
  border-bottom:1px solid #757575;
}

.floating-input:focus {
     outline:none;
     border-bottom:2px solid #5264AE; 
}

label {
  color:#999; 
  font-size:14px;
  font-weight:normal;
  position:absolute;
  pointer-events:none;
  left:5px;
  top:5px;
  transition:0.2s ease all; 
  -moz-transition:0.2s ease all; 
  -webkit-transition:0.2s ease all;
}

.floating-input:focus ~ label, .floating-input:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ label {
  top:-18px;
  font-size:14px;
  color:#5264AE;
}



/* active state */
.floating-input:focus ~ .bar:before, .floating-input:focus ~ .bar:after {
  width:50%;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* highlighter */
.highlight {
  position:absolute;
  height:50%; 
  width:100%; 
  top:15%; 
  left:0;
  pointer-events:none;
  opacity:0.5;
}

/* active state */
.floating-input:focus ~ .highlight {
  -webkit-animation:inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
  -moz-animation:inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
  animation:inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
}

/* animation */
@-webkit-keyframes inputHighlighter {
    from { background:#5264AE; }
  to    { width:0; background:transparent; }
}
@-moz-keyframes inputHighlighter {
    from { background:#5264AE; }
  to    { width:0; background:transparent; }
}
@keyframes inputHighlighter {
    from { background:#5264AE; }
  to    { width:0; background:transparent; }
}
```

```html
<div class="floating-form">
    <div class="floating-label">      
      <input class="floating-input" type="text" placeholder=" ">
      <span class="highlight"></span>
      <label>Text</label>
    </div>

</div>
```